# Installing sublime text on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, macos

> This "Question" was asked by an unregistered user who hasn't been seen since.
> Don't waste your time and ours by answering.
> If you have enough reputation flag for closure.

I know that this is too noob but I cant just figure it out..

I would like to install sublime text 3 on my raspberry-pi however as I click on the sublime dmg file that I downloaded it asks: select an application to open apple disk image file..

What do I do from here...?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't run a Mac Os app on the PI.

Comment: See my comments on SuperAdmin's answer below, but a better solution may be to setup samba or NFS which would allow access to the files from you PC - which presumably has ST installed.

Comment: My rep is too low to make an answer, but this is possible now using Pi Apps. See https://pi-apps.io/install-app/install-sublime-text-on-raspberry-pi/. Performance is pretty awful for me, but works in a pinch when you need multiple cursors and still haven't figured out Vim :)

Answer (score 15):

Apparently the growing popularity of the Pi made the team reconsider, so there [is](https://www.sublimetext.com/download) an ARM build now. Judging by the file name, it seems to require a 64-bit OS to run.

At the time the question was asked, Sublime text [didn't have an ARM build](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/arm-build/5882/8):

> Let me clarify that statement: Given we only have a finite amount of time, any time spent maintaining an ARM build would take away time from other areas. At this stage, I believe this would result in a net negative to Sublime Text's users.

At the time, you'd have to find another editor for your RPi. For example, you could try [bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/screenshots.html):

```
sudo apt-get install bluefish
```

Comment: I sort of foolishly declined an edit here when I should have left it for you to decide what to do: Apparently there is a public ARM64 sublime text now: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/arm-build/5882/98

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

You can't install. There is no such build available for Raspberry Pi.

You can install "Caret" app(Google Chrome's app) instead.
It's just like Sublime and also a light weight one.

> Got to [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-sublime-text/eiejadjdcchfommckmikpcdnihljbpai)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-sublime-text/eiejadjdcchfommckmikpcdnihljbpai

Answer (score 2):

There is Sublime Text 4 version with build for arm64 processor, so it should work on Raspberry Pi now.

Comment: Could you share the commands you used to install it?

Comment: @Vinayak see: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an ARM build is in the works - private beta as of end of July https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/arm-build/5882/88

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

Open up terminal from the raspian menu,

type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2`

after this is done type `sudo apt-get update`

then type `sudo apt-get install sublime-text`

I hope this works. :D.

Comment: I don't think this will work as I can find no where that ST supports the arm chip. A google search turned up a way to run it under QEMU (virtualiazation), but this is not likley to have the performance the OP hoped for.

Comment: Thanks but, that indeed doesn't work!

Comment: Oh? Sorry. I will look for a different solution.

Comment: It's generally a *good idea* to try your proposed answer prior to posting. Obviously incorrect answers often get downvotes, and become clutter. This one is so clearly wrong I'd recommend deleting (or modifying) to avoid further downvotes.